# Open an URL + element value in the same frame

Tags: javascript, url, button, onclick

I have this code:

```
<form>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Enter something..." id="box">
   <button onclick="window.open('http://example.com/' + document.getElementById('box').value);">GO
   </button>
</form>
```

When the user enters a word and clicks "GO", he goes to an url+ the entered value. With this code, the page opens in a new window, but I want to open it in the same frame. How can I do it?

Comment: Adding the frame as ``_self`` or refresh the current page with ``window.location``. Your choice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following

```
window.open('http://example.com/' + document.getElementById('box').value,'_self')
```

So your code would be like this

```
<form>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Enter something..." id="box">
   <button onclick="window.open('http://example.com/' + document.getElementById('box').value, '_self');">GO
   </button>
</form>
```

Comment: The best explanation so far - Can add that the '_self' targets the window you are in specifically. You can find more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.open which will actually show some neat options that you can specify that may come in handy.

Answer (score 2):

```
window.open ('page2.htm','_self',false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of javascript.

> window.location = url + text;